# How to use jmap heap

Tags: java, jvm, jmap

I have seen in tutorials, that with command `jmap -heap<pid>`, I can receive info about heap state.

Now this command is unavailable.

There are only `jmap -dump:live,format:b,file=heap.bin` but it save data to unreadable bin format.

How can I receive heap state info using `jmap` to console?

*On Windows

Upd.
I found the answer:
On new versions Jdk we can use command:

### jhsdb jmap --heap --pid

Comment: Are you running it on Unix platform ?

Comment: No, on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
In new JDK versions it works:

```
jhsdb jmap --heap --pid <pid number>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a Unix/Linux platform execute following command to generate the heap dump.

```
kill -3 <PID of the Java Process>
```

Generated heap dump file will be either in home directory of the user executed the command, or in absolute path of the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the heapdump generated by `jmap -dump:live,format:b,file=heap.bin` with https://www.eclipse.org/mat/. MAT is able to read the binary format.

Comment: I use IntellijIDEA

Comment: I highly recommend MAT see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460410/how-can-i-analyze-a-heap-dump-in-intellij-memory-leak for more options

Comment: MAT is available as a standalone application, you don't have to use eclipse as IDE